# How to code PSQL="psql -X --username=postgres --dbname=students --no-align --tuples-only -c" using my own username?

Tags: javascript, postgresql, bash, visual-studio-code, git-bash

I changed the username=freecodecamp to my username=postgres in the insert_data.sh bash script file.

This original code

`PSQL="psql -X --username=freecodecamp --dbname=students --no-align --tuples-only -c"` 
works for a course in freecodecamp.

After the changes, my own visual studio code keeps asking for username password in the bash terminal.

I entered the correct password but the response remain the same.

The confusing part is that I already have the postgres SQL 15 installed in my laptop and I can log in to psql in a separate terminal using the same username and password.

How to solve this problem?

Comment: What's the current script now? How do you set up the environment? What response remain the same? If you can use psql command normally then I think the problem might be with your script.

Comment: This is the link to the original insert_data.sh bash script for the course that I replicated using my own visual studio code. https://github.com/rosaforrestiana/building-student-database-part-1/blob/117ea1a9591a3a9891d7a0806fbc1a7c9fe655c6/insert_data

Comment: My visual studio code has installed git bash and strove. I can also login to psql  using all those terminals including using the cmd terminal but after inserting the tuples-only -c, the response is to enter user password.

Comment: And when the correct password is entered, the response is 1. I think this is an indication of error, am I right?

Comment: `after running psql on cmd it's prompt enter password` seems normal, This depends entirely on how you deploy your PostgreSQL. Some might require a password, some might not. Read up on pg_hba.conf topics on the documentation.
And for `-c`, This is for adding command afterward, so you can run query without enter the interactive shell.

Comment: I've looked at your script. the PSQL line (line#5) seems fine; other lines should work. do you have a database named `students` with table structures suited for the script?

Comment: How you have to authenticate to PostgreSQL is determined by `pg_hba.conf`. Configure that file according to your needs.

Comment: Ponsakorn30214 - Yes, I do have the a database named students. I have tried to configure the pg_hba.conf using the visual studio code by replacing all the methods to trust but still the code doesn't work.

Comment: Laurenz Albe - How to authenticate to Postgres SQL in the pg_hba.conf file?

Comment: Now the bash script keep asking for password and after 2 lines of asking for passwords, it will load a line of data in one of the tables in my database. When I removed the tuples-only -c line of code, each code that I entered in the script, will display in the bash terminal but added with a command not found at the end

Answer (score 0):

Hi to all that tried to help to solve my problem.
I managed to run the script properly because

1. I reinstalled the visual studio code, postgres SQ, git bash and the git extension in VSC
2. Cloned another project and downloaded into the VSC for testing
3. Created my own psql SQL database same as the original script except changing the code below to my own username.

PSQL="psql -X --username=rosaforrestiana --dbname=salon --no-align --tuples-only -c

However, in the psql terminal, the response is keep asking for user password. At times 2 times, and at times 4 times.

How to remove this annoying response in the psql terminal?